# How do I get the control ID of the button whose click opened the dialog box?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a dialog box with a number of buttons. Clicking any of them will create a "child" dialog box based on a single template (if that's the right term... single child dialog definition and ID in the resource file).

For example, from the dialog procedure of the parent dialog:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wparam)) {
        case IDC_MAPBUT1:
        case IDC_MAPBUT2:
        case IDC_MAPBUT3:
        case IDC_MAPBUT4:
        case IDC_MAPBUT5:
        case IDC_MAPBUT6:
        case IDC_MAPBUT7:
        case IDC_MAPBUT8:
        case IDC_MAPBUT9:
        case IDC_MAPBUT10:
            DialogBox(
                g_hinstance,
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2),
                hwnd,
                CPUMapDlgProc);
            return TRUE;
        //etc
```

I need to know which one of the buttons was clicked (while still in the child dialog), as I'll need to read data from a corresponding struct. How can I do that?

Comment: You can check manually each button whether it has been clicked. Or, you can write a function, say "openDialog(buttonName)", and call that function in the "click" event of all buttons.

Comment: Save the value of `LOWORD(wparam)` in a global variable that `CPUMapDlgProc` can look at, or call `DialogBoxParam` and pass it as the parameter for the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

Comment: @JonathanPotter DialogBoxParam fits the bill perfectly, thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the value of `LOWORD(wparam)` in a global variable that `CPUMapDlgProc` can look at, or call `DialogBoxParam` and pass it as the parameter for the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.